# How do self-proclaimed "Githubs of music" Splice and Blend compare?

Tags: software

[Splice](https://splice.com/) and [Blend](http://blend.io/). Each company describes itself as the "Github of music." One is a USV company and the other is Betaworks. I'm sure they're both rapidly improving their feature sets, and by the time you read this, the answers below will probably be obsolete.

But which service provides the best sound quality? Which, do you think, I can rely on professionally?

Comment: What does "best" mean to you?  What are you looking for?  You'll need to be more specific in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: It looks like both do the same thing, but do it differently.  With both you upload your music in full quality, so there should be no difference in the sound.  Your best bet is to try both and see which better suits your needs and workflow.

Comment: @JoshP I am mostly just looking for a feature comparison, and in particular whether each supports pro quality bit rates.

Comment: @user9650 This is something you can figure out easily by e-mailing both services with the question about pro bit rates.